# How to get sim time in ignition gazebo

Tags: ignition-dome

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is it possible to get the sim time outside of the update callbacks in ignition gazebo? Ie is there an equivalent of `physics::World::SimTime()`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26368/how-to-get-sim-time-in-ignition-gazebo/) by [nlamprian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8391/nlamprian/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 833 on 2021-01-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You could subscribe to the `/clock` topic. Otherwise, you can get it during an update and store at a local variable.

`SimTime` was kept out of `ignition::gazebo::World` on purpose, so users would get it from the update callbacks. More info on [this tutorial](https://ignitionrobotics.org/api/gazebo/4.1/migrationworldapi.html).

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2021-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0